# Grouping values under elements FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to format the output of a query using `FOR XML` in SQL Server 2012.

Each `PART_NO` can have a varying number of `SUPPLIER_PART_NUMBER`'s mapped to it.

The table has data in the following format.

```
    PART_NO SUPPLIER_PART_NO
    ------- ----------------
    AAA     1
    AAA     2
    BBB     3
    BBB     4
    BBB     5
```

The desired output is as follows where part AAA has two supplier part numbers and part BBB has three supplier part numbers, and the supplier part numbers are nested below the part number.

```
    <root>
        <item PartNo ="AAA">
            <mpn>1</mpn>
            <mpn>2</mpn> 
        </item>
        <item PartNo ="BBB">
            <mpn>3</mpn>
            <mpn>4</mpn> 
            <mpn>5</mpn>
        </item>
    </root>
```

The closest I can get is below, but this does not group the `mpn` under `PartNo`:

```
SELECT  
    [PART_NO] as 'item/@PartNo',
    [SUPPLIER_PART_NO] as 'mpn'
FROM 
    [dbo].[supplier_part_mapping2]
ORDER BY 
    PART_NO
FOR XML PATH('') , ROOT('root');
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    p1.PART_NO as 'item/@PartNo',
    (SELECT 
         SUPPLIER_PART_NO AS 'mpn'
     FROM
         [dbo].[supplier_part_mapping2] p2
     WHERE
         p1.PART_NO = p2.PART_NO
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS 'item'
FROM 
    [dbo].[supplier_part_mapping2] p1
GROUP BY
    PART_NO
ORDER BY 
    PART_NO
FOR XML PATH('') , ROOT('root');
```

This should produce:

[image]

You basically need to **group by** the `PART_NO` so that you get only one `<item>` entry for each distinct `PART_NO`, and you need to grab the "sub-elements" as a subquery to list them all together under one parent node.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks. :)

Comment: @RitchieB: yeah - sorry - I tested with a table variable - updated my post accordingly, now it should reflect your situation fully